# Yaml won't validate

Tags: yaml, github-actions

For the life of me I can't figure out why this yaml won't validate:

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x, 14.x, 16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: >-
        git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
      - run: >-
        git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
```

It gives me a `Error : can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 27` error which doesn't lead to any promising results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which line is Line 27? If I counted correctly, it's the first `run:` line

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I've tried all kinds of combinations of the first two run lines. Some fail and others don't. I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies. I'm sure it's something dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

YAML parser is picking up the second colon on line 27.

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

You can escape the colon with [`format`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format).

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ${{ format('git{0}//', ':') }}
```